# Ember.js - run observer after computed property has completed

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.js app that includes a template with a carousel that contains a scrollable list of 'activities.' I'm using a computed property to filter and return a collection of activities, which I then use to bind to my template, which populates the carousel. The computed property that provides the collection looks like this:

```
// simplified for clarity
activities: function () {
    var model = this.get('model.content');

    model.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a.get('type') > b.get('type') ? 1 : -1;
    }.bind(this);

    return model;
}.property('model', 'controllers.browse.filter')
```

Every time the controllers.browse.filter property changes, the activities computed property is re-calculated, and the new filter criteria is applied to the model, which is working without a problem.

However, I need to 'rebind' my carousel *after* the newly filtered model is returned. Right now, I'm trying to do that with an observer like so:

```
reloadCarousel: function () {
    // pseudo code, not important to problem
    carousel.reload();
}.observes('activities')
```

The problem is that reloadCarousel is being run *as soon as* the activities property starts changing, meaning the activities property has not had time to complete and return the new model collection before the reloadCarousel observer is fired. This doesn't work, because my carousel isn't able to bind to the newly filtered model.

I searched the Ember.js docs, but can't find anything that allows me to wait until a computed property has completely finished and returned all relevant data to my template.

Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The get method returns a promise, which you could wait to fulfill and then set the activities:

```
this.get('model.content').then(function(model) {
  var activities = model.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.get('type') > b.get('type') ? 1 : -1;
  });
  // set activities
});
```